# Image Picker SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, macos, swiftui, imagepicker

i'm having problem with my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct EditUserView: View {
    @State var isUpdateSuccessful = false
    @EnvironmentObject var storageManager: StorageManager
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State var fullName = ""
    @State var email = ""
    @State var avatarURL = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @State var image = UIImage()
    @State var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        if let user = viewModel.currentUser {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        if user.photoURL == "" {
                            Image(uiImage: self.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                .background(
                                    Text(user.initials)
                                        .font(.system(size: 80))
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color(.white))
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                        .background(Color(.systemGray3))
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                )
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        }
                        else {
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: user.photoURL)){ image in
                                image
                                    .image?.resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                    .cornerRadius(34)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            try await storageManager.deleteAvatarImage(photoURL: user.photoURL)
                            try await viewModel.updateUser(withEmail: email, fullName: fullName, password: password, photoURL: "")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Delete Image")
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: nil) {
                    ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                InfoInputView(text: $fullName, title: "Full Name", content: user.fullName)
                InfoInputView(text: $email, title: "Email", content: user.email)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Button {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            let photoURL = await storageManager.uploadImageAndGetURL(image)
                            try await viewModel.updateUser(withEmail: email, fullName: fullName, password: password, photoURL: photoURL)
                            
                            // Cập nhật thành công, hiển thị thông báo
                            isUpdateSuccessful = true
                        } catch {
                            // Xử lý lỗi nếu cập nhật thất bại
                            isUpdateSuccessful = false
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Update Profile")
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.white))
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .background(Color(.black))
                    .cornerRadius(32)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .shadow(radius: 15)
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $isUpdateSuccessful) {
                    if isUpdateSuccessful {
                        Alert(title: Text("Update successful"),
                            message: Text("User profile has been updated."),
                            dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
                        )
                    }
                    else {
                        Alert(title: Text("Update failed"),
                            message: Text("User profile hasn't been updated."),
                            dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
                        )
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this view to edit user information. The changing information for user's full name and email is working just fine. The upload and delete avatar is working as well. If user.photoURL is empty, the view would look like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou0KS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou0KS.png)
when user tap in the button and choose image from library, the button will display the image that user picked. But after that, if user delete image, the button keep showing the image that user picked before. How can i reset the button label like beginning when user hasn't choose image

Comment: How about doing `self.image = UIImage()` when the user hits delete?

Comment: Unrelated but I believe that `isUpdateSuccessful` will 
always be `true` in `.alert(isPresented: $isUpdateSuccessful)` for it to proceed, 
so the `if isUpdateSuccessful {...} else {...}` is not meaningful.

Comment: i have try to set `self.image = UIImage()` but it still doesn't work. any idea else

Comment: i tried to create a func to reset photoURL value in AuthViewModel and set `self.image = UIImage()` and it finally work, thanks for your help